# union of rows in multiple files based on key using awk or linux commands

Tags: awk, union

I have 'n' files in the directory. For instance there are 3 files as shown below

file1.txt

```
"aba" 0 0 
"aba" 0 0 1
"abc" 0 1
"abd" 1 1 
"xxx" 0 0
```

file2.txt

```
"xyz" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 0 0
"aba" 0 0 0 1
"xxx" 0 0
"abc" 1 1
```

file3.txt

```
"xyx" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 
"aba" 0 1 0
"xxx" 0 0 0 1
"abc" 1 1
```

I would like to print the union of rows from all the 3 files using column 1 and column 2 as key columns. And for each row in the union print all the original columns, print the number of times (number of files) key is present in the first column and frequency in second column. A sample output will look like:

```
1  1/3  "abc" 0 1
1  1/3  "abd" 1 1
1  1/3  "xyz" 0 0
2  2/3  "abc" 1 1
3  3/3  "aba" 0 0 
3  3/3  "aba" 0 0 1
3  3/3  "xxx" 0 0
1  1/3  "xyx" 0 0
```

Could someone help to this using awk or linux commands and generalize it for n files in the  directory.

Comment: What have you tried? I don't think the specification for the output is complete. How do you determine the number of columns in the output? Why does "xxx" only have "0 0" in the output?

Comment: Hi, i did it in R and it becomes a memory intensive job for more files and i don't have an awk or linux solution. The number of columns are the original number of columns + the first two new columns. In this case "xxx 0 0" is present in all the three files and in such cases it can print from the first appearance i.e. from the first file. So, it necessarily doesn't have equal number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==1{x++} {a[$1 FS $2][x]; b[$1 FS $2]=$0} END{for(i in a){q=0;for(j in a[i]){q++};print q,q"/"x,b[i]}}' file*
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 1/3 "xyx" 0 0
1 1/3 "abc" 0 1
2 2/3 "abc" 1 1
3 3/3 "xxx" 0 0 0 1
1 1/3 "abd" 1 1 
1 1/3 "xyz" 0 0
3 3/3 "aba" 0 1 0
```

You can sort it according to the way you want.

Note: use gawk version >=4.0

Comment: thanks!! Do u mean gawk version >=4.0 for sorting or for the whole script. Bcoz when i used your code it shows the error: 'syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 FNR==1{x++} {a[$1 FS >>>  $2][ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1'

Comment: For the script because older versions of awk don't allow multidimensional arrays-  `a[x][y]`